# Pushing Geocoded Point to End of Parcel using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I am trying to geocode for trees based on addresses. Basically I need the points to show up at the end of the parcel as opposed to the center (trees don't grow in the middle of houses). I have tried using the 'Side Offset' function in my ArcMap desktop (10.5) but this seems to confuse the program and a number of the points that were regularly geocoded disappear and nothing slides to the end of the parcel.

The geocoder I built uses building parcels and the 'General- Single Field' style. It works excellently until you try to offset anything. I have also tried this with street center lines (US Addresses- Dual Ranges) but this doesn't work as well. The image below shows in orange the parcel geocoded sites and the blue is the street geocoded sites.

The data I am trying to geocode has an address ex: "1501 N 15TH ST", and a zipcode ex: "19121" in two separate fields.

I am not opposed to writing code for this, but would like to see if there was an option to do this in the ArcMap geocoder tools before I went too far.

[image: Orange dots are parcel geocoded sites, Blue dots are street geocoded sites.]

Comment: im thinking this through in postgis, if you convert the polygons to a boundary line, then you can snap the points to the line(aka the boundary of the parcel) using the st_closestpoint function...what programming language do you know?

Comment: I can code in SQL, R, and Python, but need to give the geocoder to people who don't code at all. My goal is to do the hard work then just let them do the easy stuff in the future. I do like the idea of postgis though (SQL's the best!).

Comment: ahh well I cant help you there, not so familiar with the ArcGIS geocoder but this is very possible in postgis. and yes SQL is by far my favorite

Comment: Negative buffer of parcel, convert to polyline, near with location. Run arcpy.Point(!nearx!, neary) on shape field.

Comment: Would you recommend doing this in model builder or in the python command window?

Comment: Ended up being able to do this using a typical geocode based on parcels, then a reverse geocode based on streets. This pushed the points out just enough to simulate a sidewalk tree. The two steps could be optimized with coding, but the quick 2 step process worked very well for the organization the project was for.